# Properly construct return value using node.js Promises

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am new to node.js and I am having hard time with `Promises`. I want to construct/build my result variable step by step by using `Promises`.
I "abstracted" my code just to point out the issue better. Basically what I am trying to do is to create a resulting model of several rest api calls (those calls that can be done in parallel are called in `Promise.all`).

Thank you in advance.

```
function test() {
    var result = {}; 
    var prom1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(addTwo(result)); 
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    return prom1.then(function(result) {
            promises = [];
            promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                resolve(addD(result)); 
            }));
            promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                resolve(addC(result));
            }));
            Promise.all(promises)
                         .then(result) 
    }).then(console.log(result)); //logging because I was testing
}

function addTwo(result) {
    result.a = "a";
    result.b = "b";
    return result;
}

function addD(result) {
    result.d = "d";
}

function addC(result) {
    result.c = "c";
}

test();
```

The output that expected was: `{ a: 'a', b: 'b', d: 'd', c: 'c' }`, but instead I got: `{ a: 'a', b: 'b' }`

I understand that if I call `then()` on a `Promise`, that I will have in that block access to the return value from the promise, but can I adjust my code somehow to "build" the result variable in the then calls with using Promise.all at some point?

Comment: You need to pass a callback to `then`, like `.then(() => { return result })` or `.then(() => { console.log(result); })`.

Comment: Btw, I'm not sure what parts of the code you abstracted, but you should have the asynchronous functions `addTwo`, `addC` and `addD` create and *`return`* the promises themselves. Also you don't need `new Promise` here, you could just have used `Promise.resolve(…)`.

Comment: @Bergi thank you for the help, it worked! I also restructed my code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to `return` your `Promise.all(promises)` so that its result is chained to the `then` where you have `console.log(result)`.
2. I believe you have an error at the line `Promise.all(promises).then(result)`, you pass `result` to `then` but `then` expects a function as an argument, not an object

Consider using `async/await` cause it's less confusing than these `Promise` chains

Answer (score 0):

In a more ES8 way with the async/await syntax you could escape the .then().catch() struggle. I feel like it's easier to get how promises work this way.

```js
async function test() {
    try {
        let result = {}
        await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            resolve(addTwo(result))
        })
        let promises = []
        promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            resolve(addD(result))
        }))
        promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            resolve(addC(result))
        }))
        await Promise.all(promises)
        return result
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
}
```

Note that you'll have to await your test function result